# how to edit role permissions with discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a little problem. 
I want my bot to create a 'Muted' role when it joins a server. To achieve this, I have written this code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
        with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
                prefixes = json.load(f)


        prefixes[str(guild.id)] = "b!"

        with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:
                json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

        await guild.create_role(name="Muted")
        for role in guild.roles:
                if role.name == "Muted":
                        await role.edit(reason = None, colour = discord.Colour.orange(), read_messages = True, read_message_history = True, connect = True, speak = True, send_messages = False)
```

This code correctly creates the role and correctly set the colour.
However, it set none of the role's permissions.

Could anyone help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a [`Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions) argument to the `permissions` argument of `edit`

```
perms = Permissions()
perms.update(read_messages = True, read_message_history = True, connect = True, speak = True, send_messages = False)
await role.edit(reason = None, colour = discord.Colour.orange(), permissions=perms)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Permissions class

you need to use discord.Permissions

*class discord.Permissions(permissions=0, kwargs)*

## Example

```
permissions = discord.Permissions()
permissions.update(kick_members = False)
await role.edit(reason = None, colour = discord.Colour.blue(), permissions=permissions)
```

learn more here https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissions
:)